# Frameworks or any Solutions for authentications/security/ login management in Java Web Applications

Tags: appsec, web-application, authentication, java

I am looking for a framework/solution for authentication/ user-login management/ security  in java web application that can make the naive developer's job easier/faster and make the application relatively more secured against potential threats.

---

P.S. :  I'm using JSF 2.0 as the front-end development framework in my web application.

Comment: For internal/external use? Customers/employees?

Comment: for external use.. a web app that is open to a general audience similar to a social networking applications

Answer (score 3):

Check out [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/)'s [ESAPI (Enterprise Security API)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Esapi).

> ESAPI (The OWASP Enterprise Security API) is a free, open source, web application security control library that makes it easier for programmers to write lower-risk applications. The ESAPI libraries are designed to make it easier for programmers to retrofit security into existing applications. The ESAPI libraries also serve as a solid foundation for new development.

While it is ported to several languages and frameworks, it started as a Java EE project. It's a very large and flexible framework, should meet most of your needs.

---

And as far as authentication and user management goes, *strongly* consider using OpenID (or something like that), so you dont have to manage it at all. Depending on your usecases and userbase, this can be a huge benefit, to you AND your users.

Comment: Thanks ! What do you think about Apache Shiro. I just heard some good comments about it.

Comment: Dont really know Apache Shiro, so I can't comment on it... But OWASP ESAPI is considered the goto package.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the freedom to choose the web application framework you are using, I can recommend web2py.  It has built-in support for authentication, log-in management, and many other security needs.  It was designed right from the get-go to make many security problems (e.g., XSS, SQL injection, session management attacks, etc.) nearly impossible.  And, as a bonus, it is beautiful, clean, and easy-to-learn.

web2py: Give it a try.